# Prevent users from opening multiple instance of same website PHP

Tags: javascript, php, browser, tabs

I need only one tab accessible for my website. When he tries to open in new tab or even tries to copy and paste the url in new tab should clear the user's session and logout from the application.

There are several reasons,

1. When a user opens a new tab connecting to the same application - the session id is the same.
2. Imagine that this user has reached a page X in the application flow  from the first tab.
3. When he opens the second tab he might be in one of the following scenarios - depending how the second tab was opened - new tab, duplicate tab (this copies the URL to the newly opened tab), or new session.
   All of the above will "confuse" the server as to what the next valid state of the application is, and could override data entered in different tab, without his/her knowledge
   What I want is to prevent a single user to have several tabs in the same session, i.e. only one tab/window per user, per session.

**Including the below script in dashboard.php after login**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") 
    {
        if (sessionStorage.pagecount) 
        {
            sessionStorage.removeItem('pagecount');
            window.location='logout.php';
        } 
        else
        {
            sessionStorage.pagecount = 1;
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        sessionStorage.removeItem('pagecount');
        window.location='logout.php';
    }    
});
```

**Below code in other sub pages in the application**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{       
    if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") 
    {
        if (sessionStorage.pagecount) 
        {
            sessionStorage.pagecount = Number(sessionStorage.pagecount) + 1;
        } 
        else 
        {
            sessionStorage.removeItem('pagecount');
            window.location='logout.php';
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        sessionStorage.removeItem('pagecount');
        window.location='logout.php';
    }   
});
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [How to restrict my app to a single browser tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844415/how-to-restrict-my-app-to-a-single-browser-tab)

Comment: But am not satisfied with the solution. How can I implement it? @AngelosChalaris

Comment: Read the question I have linked to. Most aswers suggest either that it is a bad practice or that there is a workaround, but not a very straightforward solution for the kind of thing you are interested in implementing. If you want help with a particular implementation of one of the answers of the question I've linked to, try implementing it yourself and see what problems you might encounter and then try updating your question with more details.

Comment: What you wish is a server side feature. Some websites are able to do that using Websockets or a similar technology, so a server could push the logout to the browser in real time. Any other method will mean tampering with the browser normal behavior, which may result in some security concerns/issues for the end user.

Comment: a) why would you even ever concider this? what would anybody need this for? b) i'm pretty sure this would actively p*ss off every legitimate user c) i'm pretty sure there is no possible way of achieving this that can't be "hacked" within seconds d) what have you tried so far to achieve this?

Comment: This functionality is for the internal operations not for the general use, Please understand the requirement and help me @FranzGleichmann

Comment: @Steffi that does not in any way explain anything. it opens more questions instead, for example: how would one internal, authorised user, and another non-authorised user EVER use tabs in the same browser instance? i think you should explain much more thoroughly what exactly you are trying to achieve in the long run with this.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann , its that there is no possibility of non-authorised user in my application. Like the bank websites, I do not want any user to open multiple tabs for the application. Per login one tab ONLY.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I have edited my question with scenario and code, please update me on this asap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Added the below script after I login(say dashboard.php)**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("a").attr("target", "");
    if(typeof(Storage)              !== "undefined") 
    {
        sessionStorage.pagecount    =   1;
        var randomVal               =   Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000000) + 1); 
        window.name                 =   randomVal;
        var url                     =   "url to update the value in db(say random_value)";
        $.post(url, function (data, url)
        {
        });
    } 
    else 
    {
        var url                     =   "url to remove random_value";           
        $.post(url, function (data, url)
        {
            sessionStorage.removeItem('pagecount');
            sessionStorage.clear();
            window.location         =   'logout.php';
        });
    }    
});
</script>
```

**Added the below script in Header in rest of my pages - 'random_value' is from db for that user**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{       
    $("a").attr("target", "_self");

    if(typeof(Storage)                      !== "undefined") 
    {
        if (sessionStorage.pagecount) 
        {
            if('<?=$random_value?>'         ==  window.name)
            {
                sessionStorage.pagecount    =   Number(sessionStorage.pagecount) + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                var url                     =   "url to remove random_value";           
                $.post(url, function (data, url)
                {
                    sessionStorage.removeItem('pagecount');
                    sessionStorage.clear();
                    window.location         =   'logout.php';
                });

            }               
        } 
        else 
        {           
            var url                         =   "url to remove random_value";           
            $.post(url, function (data, url)
            {
                sessionStorage.removeItem('pagecount');
                sessionStorage.clear();
                window.location             =   'logout.php';
            });
        }
    } 
    else 
    {   
        var url                             =   "url to remove random_value";                   
        $.post(url, function (data, url)
        {
            sessionStorage.removeItem('pagecount');
            sessionStorage.clear();
            window.location                 =   'logout.php';
        });
    }   
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("a").attr("target", "");
    if(typeof(Storage)              !== "undefined") 
    {
        sessionStorage.pagecount    =   1;
        var randomVal               =   Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000000) + 1); 
        window.name                 =   randomVal;
        var url                     =   "url to update the value in db(say random_value)";
        $.post(url, function (data, url)
        {
        });
    } 
    else 
    {
        var url                     =   "url to remove random_value";           
        $.post(url, function (data, url)
        {
            sessionStorage.removeItem('pagecount');
            sessionStorage.clear();
            window.location         =   'logout.php';
        });
    }    
});
</script>
```