# How to limit user to open that page in only one tab in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I search on this but could not find useful for me or i did't understand if there were any .

I went through one page that has help for .net but i couldn't understand that to follow for laravel .

I want the certain page to be open in only one tab and wouldn't open in another tab if one tab is active .
I have upload form in that page and first user enter text field to upload and on clicking save and continue user move to next tab in nav-tab which contain dropzone form to input image and video file . On going to next tab all input text field which are inputed are stored in session .

So if user open another browser tab and open that page and input that field to upload other file , the session variable get overwrite .

So i want that user limited to only one tab for that page only .

Sorry if my poor English made hard to figure my problem .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to restrict my app to a single browser tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844415/how-to-restrict-my-app-to-a-single-browser-tab)

Comment: Did u read?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23690666/check-if-my-website-is-open-in-another-tab

Comment: You mean one browser tab only?

Comment: yes i want to open that in single tab only

Comment: @adam thanks for referencing these  .. i have webt through similar:       
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574970/how-to-detect-if-user-open-two-tabs-for-same-session   i am going through your references now ..

Comment: i went through them  , i am not that smart in js/jquery and this topic related isnot my skill zone in  in js/jquery .. i couldn't do that what i needed to do .